# Undefined reference is confusing me

Tags: c, reference, undefined

I have no idea why i get the reference errors and i don't understand how to fix them.
I am completly new to this, so any help is apriciated.

As far as i understand the rpcdce.h should contain whatever it is referencing, and it does, but it just doesn't work.
Im completly lost, im sorry for shitty info.

```
// Added the pragma line below to work with Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2005 Express edition
// Skype:TheUberOverLord
#pragma comment(lib, "Rpcrt4.lib")
// tab size: 2
// following special commands are recognized and handled by this client
//   #quit
//   #exit
//     terminate client
//   #dbgon
//     turn on debug printing of windows messages
//   #dbgoff
//     turn off debug printing of windows messages
//   #connect
//     discover skype api
//   #disconnect
//     terminate connection to skype api
// all other commands are sent "as is" directly to Skype
// (no UTF-8 translation is done at present)

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <rpcdce.h>

HWND hInit_MainWindowHandle;
HINSTANCE hInit_ProcessHandle;
char acInit_WindowClassName[128];
HANDLE hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent;
bool volatile fGlobal_ThreadRunning=true;
UINT uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIAttach;
UINT uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover;
HWND hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle=NULL;
#if defined(_DEBUG)
    bool volatile fGlobal_DumpWindowsMessages=true;
#else
    bool volatile fGlobal_DumpWindowsMessages=false;
#endif
DWORD ulGlobal_PromptConsoleMode=0;
HANDLE volatile hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle=NULL;

enum {
    SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS=0,                               // Client is successfully attached and API window handle can be found in wParam parameter
    SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_PENDING_AUTHORIZATION=1, // Skype has acknowledged connection request and is waiting for confirmation from the user.
                                                                                                    // The client is not yet attached and should wait for SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS message
    SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_REFUSED=2,                               // User has explicitly denied access to client
    SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_NOT_AVAILABLE=3,                 // API is not available at the moment. For example, this happens when no user is currently logged in.
                                                                                                    // Client should wait for SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_API_AVAILABLE broadcast before making any further
                                                                                                    // connection attempts.
    SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_API_AVAILABLE=0x8001
};

bool Global_Console_ReadRow( char *pacPromptBuffer, unsigned int uiMaxLength)
    {
    HANDLE hConsoleHandle, hDuplicatedConsoleHandle;
    DWORD ulCharactersRead, ulConsoleMode;
    unsigned int uiNewLength;
    BOOL fReadConsoleResult;
    bool fReturnStatus;
    char cCharacter;

    fReturnStatus=false;
    while((hConsoleHandle=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
        if( DuplicateHandle( GetCurrentProcess(), hConsoleHandle,
                GetCurrentProcess(), &hDuplicatedConsoleHandle, 0, FALSE,
                DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)==FALSE )
            break;
        GetConsoleMode( hDuplicatedConsoleHandle, &ulConsoleMode);
        SetConsoleMode( hDuplicatedConsoleHandle, ENABLE_LINE_INPUT|ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT|ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
        hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle=hDuplicatedConsoleHandle;
        ulGlobal_PromptConsoleMode=ulConsoleMode;
        fReadConsoleResult=ReadConsole( hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle,
            (LPVOID)pacPromptBuffer, uiMaxLength, &ulCharactersRead, NULL);
        if( hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle==(HANDLE)0 )
            break;
        hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle=(HANDLE)0;
        SetConsoleMode( hDuplicatedConsoleHandle, ulConsoleMode);
        CloseHandle(hDuplicatedConsoleHandle);
        if( fReadConsoleResult==FALSE || ulCharactersRead>uiMaxLength )
            break;
        pacPromptBuffer[ulCharactersRead]=0;
        uiNewLength=ulCharactersRead;
        while(uiNewLength!=0)
            {
            cCharacter=pacPromptBuffer[uiNewLength-1];
            if( cCharacter!='\r' && cCharacter!='\n' )
                break;
            uiNewLength--;
            }
        pacPromptBuffer[uiNewLength]=0;
        fReturnStatus=true;
        break;
        }
    if( fReturnStatus==false )
        pacPromptBuffer[0]=0;
    return(fReturnStatus);
    }

void Global_Console_CancelReadRow(void)
    {
    if( hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle!=(HANDLE)0 )
        {
        SetConsoleMode( hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle, ulGlobal_PromptConsoleMode);
        CloseHandle(hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle);
        hGlobal_PromptConsoleHandle=(HANDLE)0;
        }
    }

static LRESULT APIENTRY SkypeAPITest_Windows_WindowProc(
    HWND hWindow, UINT uiMessage, WPARAM uiParam, LPARAM ulParam)
    {
    LRESULT lReturnCode;
    bool fIssueDefProc;

    lReturnCode=0;
    fIssueDefProc=false;
    switch(uiMessage)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            hInit_MainWindowHandle=NULL;
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_COPYDATA:
            if( hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle==(HWND)uiParam )
                {
                PCOPYDATASTRUCT poCopyData=(PCOPYDATASTRUCT)ulParam;
                printf( "Message from Skype(%u): %.*s\n", poCopyData->dwData, poCopyData->cbData, poCopyData->lpData);
                lReturnCode=1;
                }
            break;
        default:
            if( uiMessage==uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIAttach )
                {
                switch(ulParam)
                    {
                    case SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS:
                        printf("!!! Connected; to terminate issue #disconnect\n");
                        hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle=(HWND)uiParam;
                        break;
                    case SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_PENDING_AUTHORIZATION:
                        printf("!!! Pending authorization\n");
                        break;
                    case SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_REFUSED:
                        printf("!!! Connection refused\n");
                        break;
                    case SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                        printf("!!! Skype API not available\n");
                        break;
                    case SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_API_AVAILABLE:
                        printf("!!! Try connect now (API available); issue #connect\n");
                        break;
                    }
                lReturnCode=1;
                break;
                }
            fIssueDefProc=true;
            break;
        }
    if( fIssueDefProc )
        lReturnCode=DefWindowProc( hWindow, uiMessage, uiParam, ulParam);
    if( fGlobal_DumpWindowsMessages )
        {
        printf( "WindowProc: hWindow=0x%08X, MainWindow=0x%08X, Message=%5u, WParam=0x%08X, LParam=0x%08X; Return=%ld%s\n",
            hWindow, hInit_MainWindowHandle, uiMessage, uiParam, ulParam, lReturnCode, fIssueDefProc? " (default)":"");
        }
    return(lReturnCode);
    }

bool Initialize_CreateWindowClass(void)
    {
    unsigned char *paucUUIDString;
    RPC_STATUS lUUIDResult;
    bool fReturnStatus;
    UUID oUUID;

    fReturnStatus=false;
    lUUIDResult=UuidCreate(&oUUID);
    hInit_ProcessHandle=(HINSTANCE)OpenProcess( PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if( hInit_ProcessHandle!=NULL && (lUUIDResult==RPC_S_OK || lUUIDResult==RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY) )
        {
        if( UuidToString( &oUUID, &paucUUIDString)==RPC_S_OK )
            {
            WNDCLASS oWindowClass;

            strcpy( acInit_WindowClassName, "Skype-API-Test-");
            strcat( acInit_WindowClassName, (char *)paucUUIDString);

            oWindowClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_DBLCLKS;
            oWindowClass.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)&SkypeAPITest_Windows_WindowProc;
            oWindowClass.cbClsExtra=0;
            oWindowClass.cbWndExtra=0;
            oWindowClass.hInstance=hInit_ProcessHandle;
            oWindowClass.hIcon=NULL;
            oWindowClass.hCursor=NULL;
            oWindowClass.hbrBackground=NULL;
            oWindowClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
            oWindowClass.lpszClassName=acInit_WindowClassName;

            if( RegisterClass(&oWindowClass)!=0 )
                fReturnStatus=true;

            RpcStringFree(&paucUUIDString);
            }
        }
    if( fReturnStatus==false )
        CloseHandle(hInit_ProcessHandle),hInit_ProcessHandle=NULL;
    return(fReturnStatus);
    }

void DeInitialize_DestroyWindowClass(void)
    {
    UnregisterClass( acInit_WindowClassName, hInit_ProcessHandle);
    CloseHandle(hInit_ProcessHandle),hInit_ProcessHandle=NULL;
    }

bool Initialize_CreateMainWindow(void)
    {
    hInit_MainWindowHandle=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        acInit_WindowClassName, "", WS_BORDER|WS_SYSMENU|WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 128, 128, NULL, 0, hInit_ProcessHandle, 0);

    return(hInit_MainWindowHandle!=NULL? true:false);
    }

void DeInitialize_DestroyMainWindow(void)
    {
    if( hInit_MainWindowHandle!=NULL )
        DestroyWindow(hInit_MainWindowHandle),hInit_MainWindowHandle=NULL;
    }

void Global_MessageLoop(void)
    {
    MSG oMessage;

    while(GetMessage( &oMessage, 0, 0, 0)!=FALSE)
        {
        TranslateMessage(&oMessage);
        DispatchMessage(&oMessage);
        }
    }

void __cdecl Global_InputProcessingThread(void *)
    {
    static char acInputRow[1024];
    bool fProcessed;

    if( SendMessageTimeout( HWND_BROADCAST, uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover, (WPARAM)hInit_MainWindowHandle, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, NULL)!=0 )
        {
        while(Global_Console_ReadRow( acInputRow, sizeof(acInputRow)-1))
            {
            if( _stricmp( acInputRow, "#quit")==0 ||
                    _stricmp( acInputRow, "#exit")==0 )
                break;
            fProcessed=false;
            if( _stricmp( acInputRow, "#dbgon")==0 )
                {
                printf( "SkypeControlAPIAttach=%u, SkypeControlAPIDiscover=%u, hInit_MainWindowHandle=0x%08lX\n",
                    uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIAttach, uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover, hInit_MainWindowHandle);
                fGlobal_DumpWindowsMessages=true,fProcessed=true;
                }
            if( _stricmp( acInputRow, "#dbgoff")==0 )
                fGlobal_DumpWindowsMessages=false,fProcessed=true;
            if( _stricmp( acInputRow, "#connect")==0 )
                {
                SendMessageTimeout( HWND_BROADCAST, uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover, (WPARAM)hInit_MainWindowHandle, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, NULL);
                fProcessed=true;
                }
            if( _stricmp( acInputRow, "#disconnect")==0 )
                {
                hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle=NULL;
                printf("!!! Disconnected\n");
                fProcessed=true;
                }
            if( fProcessed==false && hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle!=NULL )
                {
                COPYDATASTRUCT oCopyData;

                // send command to skype
                oCopyData.dwData=0;
                oCopyData.lpData=acInputRow;
                oCopyData.cbData=strlen(acInputRow)+1;
                if( oCopyData.cbData!=1 )
                    {
                    if( SendMessage( hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hInit_MainWindowHandle, (LPARAM)&oCopyData)==FALSE )
                        {
                        hGlobal_SkypeAPIWindowHandle=NULL;
                        printf("!!! Disconnected\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    SendMessage( hInit_MainWindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    SetEvent(hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent);
    fGlobal_ThreadRunning=false;
    }

int main(void)
    {
    // create window class
    //   create dummy/hidden window for processing messages
    //     run message loop thread
    //       do application control until exit
    //       exit: send QUIT message to our own window
    //             wait until thred terminates
    //   destroy main window
    // destroy window class
    uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIAttach=RegisterWindowMessage("SkypeControlAPIAttach");
    uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover=RegisterWindowMessage("SkypeControlAPIDiscover");
    if( uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIAttach!=0 && uiGlobal_MsgID_SkypeControlAPIDiscover!=0 )
        {
        if( Initialize_CreateWindowClass() )
            {
            if( Initialize_CreateMainWindow() )
                {
                hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent=CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
                if( hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent!=NULL )
                    {
                    if( _beginthread( &Global_InputProcessingThread, 64*1024, NULL)!=(unsigned long)-1 )
                        {
                        Global_MessageLoop();
                        Global_Console_CancelReadRow();
                        WaitForSingleObject( hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent, INFINITE);
                        }
                    CloseHandle(hGlobal_ThreadShutdownEvent);
                    }
                DeInitialize_DestroyMainWindow();
                }
            DeInitialize_DestroyWindowClass();
            }
        }
    }
```

Error message:

```
Debug\msgapitest.o||In function `Z28Initialize_CreateWindowClassv':|
C:\Users\Morten\Desktop\msgapitest\msgapitest.cpp|180|undefined reference to `UuidCreate@4'|
C:\Users\Morten\Desktop\msgapitest\msgapitest.cpp|184|undefined reference to `UuidToStringA@8'|
C:\Users\Morten\Desktop\msgapitest\msgapitest.cpp|205|undefined reference to `RpcStringFreeA@4'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-reference+c; usually there's some library missing.

Comment: Yeah, rpcrt4.lib is likely not being included in the link.  Can you post the Makefile?  I don't think the #pragma comment will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a new Win32 console application project in Visual Studio 2010 Pro, added a main.c, copied your code in, and it compiles and links fine.

I have the RpcRT4.lib in:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\IA64\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\
```

Along with the other comments, I'm assuming your linker doesn't know where to find that lib. Do you know where it is on your system? You can add the path to it to your included library directories in Visual Studio project properties.